# How to wrap JSON object to single-element array in Java

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

I have a class in Java that I want to convert to JSON. The server which accepts this input **expects a single-element JSON array, containing a key-value map**

For instance, if you have a class as shown:

```
public class Input {

    private String id1;
    private int id2;
    private String s1;
    private String s2;
    private String s3;
    ...
}

// Code which converts above class to JSON string:
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
Input input = new Input(id1, id2, s1, s2, s3);
System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(input));

// Actual Output:
{"id1":"...","id2":...,"s1":"c...","s2":"...","s3":"..."}

// Expected Output:
[{"id1":"...","id2":...,"s1":"c...","s2":"...","s3":"..."}]
```

Any idea how to get the 'Expected Output'?

Comment: Just put your output into an array?

Comment: @marsnebulasoup, could you please share the code for that?

Comment: System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Object[] { input })); => It looks like this does the trick!

Comment: @Jared Instead of `new Object[] { input }` you can also use `Collections.singletonList(input)`.

Comment: No problem @Jared. Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can put your JSONObject into JSONArray like shown below.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("firstName", firstName);
obj.put("lastName", lastName);

JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.put(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do that (given the poor question specs)

The ugly

```
System.out.println("[" + objectMapper.writeValueAsString(input) + "]");
```

The good

```
Input[] input = new Input[] { new Input(id1, id2, s1, s2, s3) };
System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(input));
```

Comment: Thank you @Vincent Mimoun-Prat

Comment: I would highly discourage the first one, and the second one is invalid syntax.

Comment: Fixed the syntax, my Java is rusty. Of course #1 is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is:

```
System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Object[] { input }));
```